# Protocol method is not invoked for OCUnit testing

Tags: iphone, ipad, unit-testing

I have a protocol to write the OCUnit test Caes

```
@interface ClassDeclaration: NSObject{

... Varables 
}
... Methods
// Protocol declartion!
@end
@protocol Message <NSObject>

-(BOOL) isValid;

@end
```

implementation method is written in another class called 'NewClassName'

```
-(BOOL) isValid{

    return (self.message != nil);
}
```

Now!

I am writing the test case for the protocol method!

```
-(void)testIsValid{
    ClassDeclaration *obj = [[ClassDeclaration alloc] init];
    SEL methodName = @selector(isValid);
    BOOL test = [obj respondsToSelector:methodName];
}
```

My question is do i can write the test case for the protocol methods?

i am trying to invoke the method  `SEL methodName = @selector(isValid);` for the test case, this method is not calling i don't to know why?  can any one let me know that protocol methods will invoke at run time so how to invoke this method through unit testing?

@All Thanks in advance!

Comment: @All Any one guide me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

It´s been a while since this question was asked, but in case someone stumbles over this question, i have an answer.

Take a look in the OCMock Framework. With it you can mock up objects and protocols and so on. You can find the Framework [here](http://ocmock.org) and for the features look [here](http://ocmock.org/features/).

OCMock has a class method which you can use to create mocks for protocols:

```
+mockForProtocol:
```

As on ocmock.org/features described, you can create the mocks with:

```
id aMock = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(SomeProtocol)]
```

There is also a description available:

> Creates a mock object that can be used as if it were an instance of an object that implements SomeProtocol.

Thats for the topic. To learn the usage of OCMock, you can refer to following posts:

- [ocmock.org/features](http://ocmock.org/features/)
- [alexvollmer.com](http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/06/28/making-fun-of-things-with-ocmock/)
- [erikdoe](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/master/Source/OCMockTests/OCMockObjectTests.m)

In addition to those links, you can get information behind the links posted [here](http://ocmock.org/tutorials/).

Happy mocking!
Tomte